# Hiding divs when displayed with javascript getting errors - Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a site with multilingual support.

I have a few divs with the same content in multiple languages, and I'm showing the content depending on the language of the users client.

Everything works, but I get an Error which says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at mywebsite.html

The error points to the `case` which is displayed.

How can I get rid of the error?

```js
var language = navigator.language || navigator.languages[0];
console.log(language);
var languageFistTwo = language.substr(0,2); // To only keep the first 2 characters.
console.log(languageFistTwo);

switch (languageFistTwo) {
    case "sl":
        document.getElementById("sl").style.display="inline-block";
        break;  
    case "en":
        document.getElementById("en").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    case "de":
        document.getElementById("de").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    case "it":
        document.getElementById("it").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    case "hr":
        document.getElementById("hr").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    case "ru":
        document.getElementById("ru").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("en").style.display="inline-block";
}
```

```css
#sl {
    display: none;
}

#en {
    display: none;
}

#de {
    display: none;
}

#it {
    display: none;
}

#hr {
    display: none;
}

#ru {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sl">
Zdravo
</div>

<div id="en">
Hello
</div>

<div id="de">
Gutten Tag
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't add all the languages before... now I did and it doesn't show me the error any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at mywebsite.html

One of your `document.getElementById` statements is returning null. So it cannot read / update the style.

Check that you have all the elements and the IDs are correct.

You can also add the [jquery ready function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) (or equivalent) to ensure that everything is loaded before trying to access the DOM

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

---

To ensure that you handle errors correctly you should check the element exists before manipulating it

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElement")
if (element) {
  element.style.display="inline-block";
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'll implement that. I can't use jquery, is there an easy JS alternative to document.ready function?

Comment: A self invoked function at the bottom of your html page should do the job. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/6852641)

Comment: While the problem was solved by adding all the Divs, I assume this would be the simplest solution to resolve the problem, so I'm accepting this anwser. Again, I would like to thank everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, when this code is executed, the DOM is not ready and the element with the id equal to the current language is not defined yet

---

I would simplify the code by keeping the `JS` code as simple as possible, making the `CSS` work for you

```
var language = navigator.language || navigator.languages[0];
document.documentElement.classList.add(language.substr(0,2));
```

this will create a class to the `root` element with the current language

Then the CSS could be

```
#sl, #en, #de, #it, #hr, #ru {
    display: none;
}

.sl #sl,
.en #en,
.de #de,
.it #it,
.hr #hr,
.ru #ru { display: inline-block; } 

// default value if the language is not available
html:not(.sl):not(.en):not(.de):not(.it):not(.hr):not(.ru) #en {
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Doing so, if you need to add another languages you just need to update 2 selectors in the `CSS` and you don't need to wait for the `DOM` to be ready (as soon as the element is in the `DOM` the style will be instantly applied)

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to decypher the CSS first, but by your description it looks promising.

Comment: Could you help me decypher the JS? so we're adding a `documentElement` to the document, which will be added to root (`html`). To that, we are appending a list of Classes (`classList`), with names obtained by `language.substr(0, 2)`? Is this somewhat correct? So basically the whole html document would have a class "en"

Comment: document.documentElement is the `html` element. classList is an interface for class manipulation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList. and yes, The HTML element has a class with the language detected.

Comment: already have the link opened. thanks for the document.documentElement. =)

Comment: One last question, after this i think i get it. So `.sl #sl`, `.en #en` etc is only shown if the 1st "argument"/class is true. Correct?

Comment: exactly, @DrDoom

Answer (score 1):

test if your div exist.

```js
var language = navigator.language || navigator.languages[0];
console.log(language);
var languageFistTwo = language.substr(0,2); // To only keep the first 2 characters.
console.log(languageFistTwo);

var langs = ["sl","de","it","hr","fr","ru","en"];
if(langs.includes(languageFistTwo) && document.getElementById(languageFistTwo) != null){
      document.getElementById(languageFistTwo).style.display="inline-block";
}else{
    document.getElementById("en").style.display="inline-block";
}
```

```css
#sl, #en, #de,  #it, #hr, #ru, #fr {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="fr">
Bonjour
</div>

<div id="sl">
Zdravo
</div>

<div id="en">
Hello
</div>

<div id="de">
Gutten Tag
</div>

and so on and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the JS code. I'll likely implement it